# HttpURLConnection connecting to a localhost works on Android 7 but not on Android 10

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

This is a simple code sample that I use to write/read a message to/from a localhost. I tested on an Android emulator. It works on Android 7 but not on Android 10. On Android 10, I found the program hangs on `conn.getOutputStream()`. How can I update my code to make it work on Android 10?

```
URL url = null;
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
   url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3016/");
   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
   try(BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()))) {
       bw.write("some messages...");
   }
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
      String line = null;
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line);
      }
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why?  Is this some sort of test code where you just want to try out socket programming?  Or are you doing this as a production implementation?  Because there are other methods of communicating across an app and between apps on Android, and running even a local server is a bad idea-  the Android OS with its power saving features is not a good fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since API-28 (Android 8.0), `HTTP` is not permitted by default. (See [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).)

You must permit *CleartextTraffic* explicitly when you use `HTTP` other than `HTTPS`.

Manifest.xml:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```